# Best practice for tables with varying content

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, database-schema

Currently I am working on a problem where I have to log data in a Oracle10g database. I want to store data from up to 40 devices (but not necessarily always 40) as one data point, these share a bit of information and the rest is device specific.

So I could either create arrays for every device-specific column and if the device is in use the according array field is getting populated.

```
ID TIMESTAMP BOARD DEVICE_ID[40] ERROR_CNT[40] TEMP[40] MORE_DATA[40]...
```

But I think I would be wasting a lot of database space by doing it like that, because the arrays would be hardly populated

The other method I can think of would be to just use the same ID for a multi-line entry and then I put as many rows into the table as I have used devices.

```
ID TIMESTAMP BOARD DEVICE_ID ERROR_CNT TEMP MORE_DATA
1  437892    1     1         100       25   xxx
1  437892    1     2         50        28   yyy
```

Now the shared information is multiple times in the database and the data is shattered among multiple lines.

Another issue is that there might be columns used by a part of the devices and some do not carry that information, so there might be even more unused fields. So maybe it would be best to create multiple tables and split the devices into groups according to the information they have and log their data in the corresponding tables.

I appreciate any help, maybe I am even paranoid about wasted db space and should not worry about that and simply follow the 'easiest' approach, which I think would be the one with arrays.

Comment: How many records will you need to store?

Comment: I think I am going to log data every 5 minutes for up to 1000 hours (6 weeks), so this will be about 12000 records in that time frame.

Comment: By 'arrays' do you mean nested tables, or your own object type, or something else? Seems like you only need two tables, one with ID (primary key), timestamp and board; and a second with ID (foreign key) and the device-specific data. You haven't said how you will query and use the data, but views/materialized could be used to denormalise if needed. I think you're worrying too much about space though; unused columns won't use generally use any (significant) space.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so I was indeed too focused on avoiding empty columns, so I think I will just create a table with all of the occasionally used columns aswell. I would create my own types and use these to have 'arrays', e.g. CREATE TYPE DEVICE_ID IS VARRAY(40) OF NUMBER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never store arrays in a database.  Violating [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is a big mistake.

Worry more about how the data is queried than how it is stored.  Keep the data model "dumb" and there are literally millions of people who can understand how to use it.  There are probably only a few hundred people who understand Oracle object types.

For example, using object types, here is the simplest code to create a table, insert data, and query it:

```
drop table device;

create or replace type error_count_type is table of number;

create table device(id number, error_count error_count_type)
nested table error_count store as error_count_table;

insert into device values(1, error_count_type(10, 20));
commit;

select sum(column_value) error_count
from device
cross join table(error_count);
```

Not many people or tools understand creating types, `store as`, instantiating types, `COLUMN_VALUE`, or `TABLE(...)`.  Internally, Oracle stores arrays as tables anyway so there's no performance benefit.

Do it the simple way, with multiple tables.  As Gordon pointed out, it's a small database anyway.  Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too long for a comment:

1000 hours * 12/hour * 40 devices = 480,000 rows.

This is not a lot of data, so I wouldn't worry about duplication of values.  You might want to go with the "other method" because it provides a lot of flexibility.

You can store all the data in columns, but if you get the columns wrong, you have to start messing around with `alter table` statements and that might affect queries you have already written.